# Can we get the propeties files data in ENUM as Constants

Tags: java, enums

I have a ENUM example

```
public enum TestClass {
    DATA_A ("A","CLASS A"),
    DATA_B ("B","CLASS B"),
    DATA_C ("C","CLASS C");
}
```

As my enum values keep on increasing, can I put all these values into a properties files 
and not need to do any changes inside the Enum if in future the values get changed or added ?

Comment: "As my enum values are keep on increasing" it's probably not best considered an enum then.

Comment: I'm not a java dev, more of .net focused person. But if enums work anything like they do in C#, then I don't think an enum is best here. Have you considered using a database of some sort or even just a json file deserialized into a list/dictionary ?

Comment: Yes @AndyTurner You are correct, as this is a part of legacy code, need a lot of modification , if i will not use the Existing enum.